# NetLogo: World size as a decimal

Tags: netlogo, hexagonal-tiles

In NetLogo, I'm trying to create a hexagonal grid where all of the hexagons are equilateral. While the examples in the models library create hexagonal grids, they aren't equilateral, so I can't use the same method that they did. In order to make this grid and still have the world wrap horizontally, I need to set the world's width to be a very specific decimal, but I can't find a way to set it to be anything but an integer.
Is it possible to set the dimensions of the world to decimals? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is impossible. The world size is measured in patches, and the dimensions of a patch are always 1x1. There's no such thing as a partial patch.

Comment: Another user suggested using `resize-world`, e.g. `resize-world -12.3 12.3 -12.3 12.3`, but it doesn't work; the 0.3 part is discarded, so the result is the same as with `resize-world -12 12 -12 12` (namely patch coordinates with the given ranges, and turtle coordinates ranging from -12.5 to 12.49999...).